# InAppBrowser plugin: How embed an angular application and detect its change of url on loadstop

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, inappbrowser

This is my question: I am developing a website in Angular that I would like to embed from IONIC with the plugin "InAppBrowser".

Normally working with ASP I can detect the change of url in the loadstop and loadstart methods but from Angular, with its routing, I can not access the event and I have no way to inject javascript or css with this plugin.

Does anyone think of a way to do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you attach your code to the post and some logs?

Comment: Unafortunatly i can't because it's a job project. Only can describe the problem :( Anyway the code it's simple, only create an instance of inappbrowser and inject the event on loadstop